# What is the difference between "using namespace Bar" and "using Bar::Foo"?

Tags: c++, name-lookup

I have the code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {

};

namespace Bar {
    struct Foo {

    };
}

namespace Baz
{
    void baz(const Foo &)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Baz::baz(Bar::Foo());
}
```

Compiler can't figure out which `Foo` want to use and produces the error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:23:19: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const Foo&' from expression of type 'Bar::Foo'
   23 |     Baz::baz(Bar::Foo());
      |                   ^~~~~
main.cpp:15:14: note: in passing argument 1 of 'void Baz::baz(const Foo&)'
   15 |     void baz(const Foo &)
      |
```

[Online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/925d64bc4f34571f)

---

Of course the simplest solution is to use either `::Foo` or `::Baz::Foo`, but I want to fix all possible ambiguities with O(1) lines of code.

My first idea was `using namespace Bar` inside `Baz` namespace:

```
namespace Baz
{
using namespace Baz;
//...
```

> using-declaration: makes the symbol name from the namespace ns_name accessible for unqualified lookup as if declared in the same class scope, block scope, or namespace as where this using-declaration appears.

I expected that all `Bar` names become part of `Baz` namespace, and unqualified lookup prefers `Baz::Foo`. But for some reason it doesn't work

[Online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0302f133132abf3)

---

But `using Bar::Foo;`, in turn, does the trick. And that confuses me even more

```
namespace Baz
{
    using Bar::Foo;
```

[Online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59fc44a7d9f33065)

---

So, my question is: What is the difference between `using namespace Bar` and `using Bar::Foo` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) is your friend.

As regards `using namespace ns_name;` it reads

> [using-directive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives): From the point of view of unqualified [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) of any name after a using-directive and until the end of the scope in which it appears, every name from *ns_name* is visible as if it were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the using-directive and *ns_name*.

As regards `using ns_name::name;` it reads

> [using-declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations): makes the symbol *name* from the namespace *ns_name* accessible for [unqualified lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) as if declared in the same class scope, block scope, or namespace as where this using-declaration appears.

It seems complicated, but it isn't. Furthermore, learning things explained this way (which is close to standardese, I'd say) pays off when it comes to diving into the depths of C++.

Comment: Now I see. **nearest** and **same**. In this case nearest == global

Answer (score 2):

`using namespace Bar::Foo` would assume that **Bar::Foo** is a **namespace** and import everything from that namespace into current scope, ex.

```
namespace Bar { namespace Foo { ... all names from this namespace would be imported ... } }
```

`using Bar::Foo` would import the **class Bar::Foo** into scope:

```
namespace Bar { class Foo {...} }
```

and if you have **nested class Foo** within **class Bar** and want to use it without class specifier, then using would look like:

```
class Bar {
  public:
    class Foo {};
};

using Foo = Bar::Foo;
// ...
// ... use Foo instead of Bar::Foo ...
```

Comment: Oops, my bad. I meant `using namespace Bar`